# Android Studio Search Structurally for xml textSize attribute

Tags: regex, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to achieve the following: Search for ever occurrence `android:textSize="XXsp"` with some number. Since these are hardcoded I want to replace these.

example:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile.login.lockout_error.title"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
```

I want this for two purposes:

Replace all hardcoded values (within certain ranges, say 12-14) with a reference to a resource (@dimen/small_text). So that I would do "manually" using search and replace structurally.

Create a replace template that would suggest the reference for that text size.

I'm off to a bad start. I can't get it to work at all.
I'm trying to use the Android Studio template `<$tag$ $attribute$="$value$"/>` and I can't figure out how it works. I'm not a regex-guru but I do understand the concept and easy regex. I tried several different combinations for the $attribute$ to find `textSize`, but no matter what I try (`textSize`, `.*textSize.*`, mark variable target for search etc.) I cannot make the search find any of the textSize attributes.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ctrl Shift F, project search. Just search for `android:textSize="1`, for example

Comment: Yes, I realise I can do a search. But the problem is not the grunt work, it's doing it in an efficient manner

Comment: You can string replace though the same interface.

Comment: Yes string replace... but you can't set up rules to go through the entire app and contextually replace hardcoded values with a specific reference depending on the value- so it's not what I'm looking for